# FindBugs plugin for Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)

Tags: java, eclipse, findbugs, eclipse-oxygen

I am currently using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a).Is FindBugs plugin supported in this version?It would be great if you could share a screenshot ?

Comment: [SpotBugs](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spotbugs-eclipse-plugin) is the unofficial successor of FindBugs and is more actively developed by the autors who previously developed the FindBugs Eclipse plug-in. SpotBugs supports the current version (4.10), the upcoming version (4.11) and the outdated version you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SpotBugs](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spotbugs-eclipse-plugin)** is the [*"spiritual successor of FindBugs"*](http://javaclipse.blogspot.com/2017/10/spotbugs-310-released.html) and is more actively developed by the authors who previously developed the FindBugs Eclipse plug-in.

SpotBugs supports the current version (4.10), the upcoming version (4.11) and the outdated version (4.7.1a) you are using.

In the [Eclipse Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spotbugs-eclipse-plugin) click on the download icon to see which Eclipse versions are officially supported:

[image]